# How to create a form that display license key (and email it to user) after the user enter their email and 10 digit code?

Tags: php, forms

I want to create a form with 'email' and '10 digit code' fields that will display a license key which matches the '10 digit code' if it's correct.

The user will also receive an email with the license key.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you running into? What specific questions do you have? Right now, it reads like you're just asking someone to write this whole functionality for you, which is not how this stack works. Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/421650/edit) with more specifics.

Comment: I'm just looking for directions on how to do it or what to look at. When I searched for license key questions it only gives results on how to sell product with license key or how to display license key in your account as endpoint.

Comment: How are you creating and distributing the license keys? No one here will know how to verify a license key if they don't know where they came from in the first place. When you're selling your product you need to create and store the keys, and create an API that allows your users to verify that key. It's a very involved process and you'd be much better off using an off-the-shelf solution. Whatever ecommerce solution you're using to sell your product would almost certainly have options.